# centos7: create service to start script bash

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, service, centos

My OS is Centos 7, I used systemd to create a service to lunch my mongodb data base, I created the service under "/usr/lib/systemd/system/", I named it "mongo.service"

when I start my service using

```
sudo systemctl start mongo.service
```

No error is displayed but I can't see the mongodb listening on the specified port 27017, which means that it did not start after all.

when I start my database using my script:

```
sudo /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/start_mongod.sh
```

the Data base start listening.

Here is what mongo.service contains

```
[Unit]
Description= mongo db data base

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/start_mongod.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is what my script start_mongod.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/bin/mongod --dbpath /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/data/db --port 27017 --smallfiles --logpath /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/log/mongoc.log --pidfilepath /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/log/mongod.pid --logappend  &
```

What Have I missed here to be able to start my mongo db as service?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you check the log in /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/log/mongoc.log

Comment: What does `sudo systemctl status mongo.service` say?

Comment: You can try `ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/iot/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/start_mongod.sh`

Comment: @Vishal: nothing in the "mongoc.log" like the operation of starting the mongodb as service was not taken into consideration, no new log have been generated by this operation.

Comment: @t_thirupathi : the systemctl status gives me this: "[egm@localhost bin]$ sudo systemctl status mongo.service
mongo.service - mongo db data base
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongo.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 10 08:47:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting mongo db data base...
Aug 10 08:47:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started mongo db data base." I tried to use "/bin/bash" but it did not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

You should make this change

```
RemainAfterExit=Yes
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)